# Sort the files in the directory recursively based on last modified date

Tags: shell, scripting, find, sort

Sort the files in the directory recursively based on last modified date

I have modified a lot of files in my directory want to know what are those files by sorting them by the last modified date and in that I want some of the extensions to be excluded

in the svn directory I have a lot of .svn files too which I don't want to show in the sort

Comment: I demo how to exclude the extension in my answer.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
find -printf "%TY-%Tm-%Td %TT %p\n" | sort -n
```

will give you something like

> 2014-03-31 04:10:54.8596422640 ./foo
>   2014-04-01 01:02:11.9635521720 ./bar

Comment: Can i exclude an file extension from the folder....

Comment: @Danny Yes, that's easy with find: `find -not -iname '*.ext'`.

Comment: find -not -path "*svn*" -not -name "*svn" -printf "%TY-%Tm-%Td %TT %p\n" | sort -n this is exactly what I needed thanks a lot @ n.st

Comment: I get `find: illegal option -- p`

Comment: Nice!! Note, adding `-f` at the beginning of the `find` command restricts it to just files, which is very helpful to avoid e.g. the directory cruft in `~.cache/pip/http`

Comment: @nealmcb that's not correct. The option is `-type f` e.g. `find -type f -printf "....`

Comment: If you get `find: illegal option -- h` (as @CodyBugstein above), you have a version of `find` that does not support `-printf`.  You will need the GNU find (`find --version` will tell you if you have the GNU version).  Note that the GNU utilities may be installed with a 'g' prefix unless you use `--with-default-names`, so `gfind` may already be installed.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to flatten the directory structure (thus sorting by date over all files in all directories, ignoring what directory the files are in) the `find`-approach suggested by @yeti is the way to go.  If you want to preserve directory structure, you might try

```
$ ls -ltR /path/to/directory
```

which sorts directory based.

Comment: this give me folder wise where as what I need is all together what are the recently modified files

Answer (score 6):

This one will list all `files`  in `<dir>` with topmost being oldest modified

```
find <dir> -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ls -ltr
```

And with this the latest modified is topmost

```
find <dir> -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ls -lt
```

Note that this only works if the list of file names doesn't exceed the total command line length limit on your system.

Comment: for reference about **command: arg list too long** http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/

Answer (score 6):

In bash, run `shopt -s globstar` first. In ksh93, run `set -o globstar` first. In zsh, you're already set.

```
ls -dltr **/*
```

This will return an error if you have so many files that the command line length limit on your system is exceeded. In zsh, you can use this instead:

```
print -rl -- **/*(Om)
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are usuig GNU find,  try:

```
find $SOMEPATH -exec stat -c '%Y %n' '{}' + | sort -n
```

Comment: You could use `find`'s `-printf` option to avoid invoking a separate process (or several, depending on the number of files). See [my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/122663/28235) for an example.

Comment: Knowing that there are other ways to do it, I *wanted* to give `stat` a chance *and* show `-exec ... +`. Really! Sometimes I think, `stat` deserves more attention... and noone should take recipes from here without reading about the ingredients and thinking about consequences...

Comment: Btw... not every find has `-printf`...

Comment: @yeti - If your *`find`* doesn't have *`-printf`,*  you can use *`-exec sh -c 'printf...'`* to get much of the same functionality. That would include access to *`$(pwd)`* for fully qualified paths as well.

Comment: I met lots of linux users never having read about `stat`. So sometimes I just want to direct some attention on `stat`... I think `stat` deserves it...

Answer (score 2):

To robustly list the filenames only using recent GNU tools:

```
find . -printf '%A@ %p\0' |
  sort -nz |
  sed -z 's/^[^ ]* //' |
  tr '\0' '\n'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
find $DIR -depth -maxdepth 3 \
    -type d -readable -printf \
    'printf "\\n%p\\n"
    ls -t --color=always "%p"\n' |\
    . /dev/stdin 2>&-
```

This avoids any argument list problems because the only argument *`ls`* will ever receive is the name of the directory you want listed. You can do this with anything you like.

The shell just *`. sources`* the *`|pipe`* as a shell script - it's the same process and doesn't have the issues you can encounter when *`execve`* is called.

In any case - the above only goes three-deep which is adjustable by changing *`maxdepth`.*  It also deep first - so you work your way backwards to your current directory from *`depth`.*

You might notice you also get *`$LSCOLORS`* - on my machine it also provides neatly printed columns and everything else you would want from *`ls`* - or, for that matter, anything you can imagine you'd wanna do with *`. source.`*

#### NO SVN

Again, this'll do anything you expect of *`ls`.* So hiding *`.svn`* files is as simple as changing the *`ls`* line to:

```
ls -t --color=always --hide="*svn" "%p"\n
```

Or if you want to see *`svn`* extensions in every folder BUT *`./svn`* you could change it so the whole command looks like this:

```
    find $DIR -depth -maxdepth 3 \
        -type d -readable -printf \
            'printf "\\n%p\\n" ; hide=
            [ "%p" = "./svn" ] && hide="*svn"
            ls -t --color=always --hide="$hide" "%p"\n' |\
    . /dev/stdin 2>&-
```

Personally, I like it with ls's *`-s`* and, if you care, *`-u`* will sort by access time rather than mod time.