# how to display the files ascending (descending) order on terminal folder?

Tags: mobaxterm

I am using MobaXterm. In the terminal folder, I have a long list of files, I put a short section of it below. Is there any way to list the files ascending (descending) order? thanks

[image]

Comment: clicking on name header ?

Comment: Oh, was that simple! It worked, thank you!

Comment: See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/122597/117549

Comment: Is there a way to sort by type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Archemar commented](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/502747/how-to-display-the-files-ascending-descending-order-on-terminal-folder/502749#comment927040_502747), since you have a graphical interface that includes the "Name" field, simply clicking on that header will sort the files by that field. Notice that the "Last modified" field is the current sort order (indicated by the arrow on it).