# List all files in a directory, recursively, sorted by modification date

Tags: bash, find, sort, printf

The main answer of [Sort the files in the directory recursively based on last modified date](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122597/sort-the-files-in-the-directory-recursively-based-on-last-modified-date) gives a method to list all files in a directory, recursively, sorted by modification date:

```
find -printf "%TY-%Tm-%Td %TT %p\n" | sort -n
```

However it doesn't list only the files, but also the directories. **How to list only the files?**

Comment: Right there in the comments: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122597/sort-the-files-in-the-directory-recursively-based-on-last-modified-date#comment1350966_122663

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tell find you only want files (`-type f`):

```
find -type f -printf "%TY-%Tm-%Td %TT %p\n" | sort -n
```